# Windows authentication for spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I am developing a spring boot(backend) + angualr UI application. This application is going to be used within domain network and outside from internet. I want all users who are connected to domain to access this application without providing any username/password. user should be authenticated against windows active directory automatically. when user tries to access the application from internet I want basic authentication to be used. I am not sure how to do this in spring boot application. Any guidance on this would be useful.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What are the alternative approaches you can't make up your mind which one to use? If it is *one* approach you don't think promising enough to invest further effort: show what you got.

Comment: https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-kerberos this could be useful for authenticating against windows AD